# Concordance correlation always less than or equal to pearson correlation

Tags: correlation, pearson-r, concordance

Can someone explain intuitively (or even mathematically) why Lin's concordance correlation coefficient (CCC) is always less than or equal to pearson's correlation coefficient (PCC). A related query exists as [How to compare concordance correlation coefficient to Pearson's r?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372360/how-to-compare-concordance-correlation-coefficient-to-pearsons-r) but there is no quantitative comparison between CCC and PCC. The reason why I say $CCC<=PCC$ is based on formula of CCC as $CCC = 2\times PCC\times \sigma_x \times \sigma_y /(\sigma_x^2+\sigma_y^2+(\mu_x-\mu_y)^2)$, where x and y are the 2 variables on which we evaluate correlation. Clearly, if $\mu_x = \mu_y $ and $\sigma_x = \sigma_y$, then $CCC=PCC$. For all other scenarios, $CCC<PCC$, based on arithmetic and geometric mean relationships.